# How to get the file name in hadoop from input file path out side mapper and reducer i.e driver class

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

To get file path in mapper or reducer we use

```
  FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)reporter.getInputSplit();
  String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
  System.out.println("File name "+filename);
  System.out.println("Directory and File name"+fileSplit.getPath().toString());

process(key,value);
```

But In input folder i had five different kind of files so need to get file name such that i can set different mappers for different  files .
example in args[0] my input folder /cloudera/test contains test.txt,dev.txt,rev.txt

if file name contains dev I should set mapper1
file name contains test I should set mapper 2
..........

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `MultipleInputs` and mappers i think i got a good link for you help that helped me too when i practiced it long back.

[MultipleInput Usage](http://halitics.blogspot.in/2013/10/multiple-input-files-example-prog.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:
FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, String.valueOf(args[0]+","+args[1]));

Where, you can mention the paths of individual files in args[0] and args[1].